# Byte by byte download using XmlHttpRequest in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was looking to implement the front end functionality to download set of videos using java script. There are bunch of processes that run on the downloaded videos. Currently I am using XmlHttpRequest that can only start processing the bytes after downloading the entire video. Below is the sample code. I have taken any http request for problem statement. Processing starts in "xmlhttp.readyState==4" block.

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/1",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I was trying to find out if there is any way to download the response in chunks and start processing it while it is getting downloaded. This is something similar to what we can do using java.io.Inputstream package. Please see a code below which reads byte by byte with a chunk size as 1 byte.

```
try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/1");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            byte buff[] = new byte[1];
            int readData = 0;
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            while (true) {
                readData = is.read(buff);
                if (readData == -1)
                    break;
                response.append(new String(buff, 0, readData));
            }
            is.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            System.out.println(response);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // handle exception
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
```

Please suggest. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Websockets perhaps https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API or use UDP/Java

Comment: You can not do that with XmlHttpRequest in Javascript. But you can break your files into smaller files and make multiple requests.